# How can I find out how much time is spend on each line in C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, profiling

I am trying to find a profiling tool with which I can find out, how much time is spend on each line of code in a C/C++ program. I am working on Linux platforms (Ubuntu, Gentoo, SL) mainly with gcc. I use gprof but sometimes I need the "per line" information.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: In GCC you can compile with` -pg` and use `gprof`. It's not exactly "per line", but something reasonably close to that.

Comment: Which is your platform ?

Comment: @Kerrak: I forgot to mention, that I use gprof but sometimes it has to be "per line".

Comment: @rotoglup: edited the post accordingly.

Comment: "Per line" doesn't really make sense, though. What about a line that defines a class, or that starts a namespace? C++ is a *language*, but you can only profile an actual *program*.

Comment: Or a "line" that's been rearranged by the compiler to be somewhere else, or was unrolled, or chucked out the window?

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us about one of those times where you needed per-line profiling and `gprof` was not enough . In my experience, in 99% of the cases where one needs such detail to find performance problems they are most probably doing something wrong in a much larger scale...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux you can use [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/). This is a sample based profiler which runs on almost any platform and supports the performance monitoring registers if they are available. On x86 it works with both AMD and Intel.

You can use it as standalone program wich will give you an annotated source, but there is a plugin available (linuxtools) for eclipse which integrates nicely into the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

[AMD CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/tools/CodeAnalyst/codeanalystwindows/Pages/default.aspx) is your best bet, it is totally free, and it works on windows and linux, though its primarily for AMD CPU's, so non-AMD CPU's won't get the MSR based profiling options. Under Windows it also has great integration for Visual Studio 2008 & 2010 as well.

for non-vendor specific, free profilers, you can try [very sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy), which also happens to be open source.

Answer (score 1):

What [Zoom](http://www.rotateright.com/) does is take stack samples on wall-clock time.

Then the percent of time any function or line of code is responsible for is the fraction of samples on which it appears.
For example, if a line of code is on 30% of stack samples, and you could avoid executing it, the total execution time would decrease by 30%

This is true regardless of I/O, recursion, competing processes, swapping, all the things that confuse many profilers.

Comment: @drhirsch: As you know from our prior conversation, there are things Zoom won't find easily either, but as profilers go, it's doing all the right things, IMHO.